# mesh doesn't follow the amature

Tags: modeling

I don't have even good english, I upload the .blend file. If someone want, just check it out.

The problem is on title and on image.
I forgot to translate the names of bones, i hope you will understand, sorry.

[image]

Thanks.

[File](https://www.mediafire.com/file/xkxro9vitz0sbfj/human.blend/file)

Comment: You don't have any vertex groups. Select the mesh first then select the armature while you hold shift, then select: "With automatic weights" in the pop-up menu.

Comment: Then press Ctrl P, then choose "With automatic weights"

Answer (score 0):

In **object mode**, first select the **mesh**, then with shift pressed select the **armature**.

**Press CTRL+P** and check the box "**With Automatic Weights**".

[image]